# Switch controlled by open/closed circuit

Tags: switches

I am looking for a specific product: a type of switch that has an 2-pin remote connector. If these 2 pins are open-circuited, it should produce no (or low) voltage (on different output channel). If those 2 pins are short-circuited, it should produce around 12V. I do not have good knowledge of eletronics components. Are there any solutions for such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

You describe a switch which outputs 12V. That is the first diagram.
However that is very simple so I then assumed you need a switch in one place which gives 12V somewhere further away. That is the second diagram.

For the 12V supply you need a battery or a 12V brick (One of these black boxes which plug into the wall). You have not specified how much current you need to switch. What is connected to the 12V?

[image: schematic]

---

From your comment: you want the remote point to switch off when the switch is pressed. The simplest way is to use a different type of relay. This way the relay only takes power as long as you press the switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvI7f8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Yes I think the second diagram is exactly what I mean. The current can be minimal - I want to use it to give a remote interlock to users (with that SW3). I just realized I made a small mistake, it should work other way around. If they SW3 is open, the 12V should be applied (this goes to a laser driver and tells it basically to shut down). If SW3 is closed, than no or low voltage shall be applied.

Comment: You need to edit this additional information into your question.

Comment: @Sstaty: If this is part of a safety circuit then you need to ensure that a failure causes the system to fail *safe* and to a more restrictive mode. i.e., If anything goes wrong the laser should turn off.

Comment: Electrically, there is no difference whatsoever between 1 and 2 (or between 3 and normally closed switch), except for additional power drain on a battery. It is only when switched circuit is powered by different supply the relay becomes necessary. I think giving these options to someone struggling with basics is not a very good idea.